# I want to print specific details from my sql server but not able to print that specific details

Tags: python, mysql

> I am facing error of output not showing the correct bookid ,which i am picking instead it picks starting one and later when i am using it again it shows all data
> any idea what to do on this plss telll
> and i have also bolded some errors in output

```
 import mysql.connector
```

#mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='123456789')

```
mycursor=mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("USE booklibrary")
question=input("Do you want to display any record??(y/n):")
if question=='y':
while question=="y":
    print("Do you have information about the record??")
    print("1-bookid")
    print("2-bookname")
    print("3-bookholdername")
    print("4-library id")
    print("5-Exit")
    choice=int(input("enter your choice:"))        
    print(mycursor.fetchall())
    if choice==1:
            bookID=input("enter the bookid:")
            mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM booklist WHERE bookid=bookID")
            data1=mycursor.fetchone()
            print(data1)
            
    elif choice==2:
           bookName=input("enter the bookname:")
           mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM booklist where bookname=bookName")
           data2=mycursor.fetchone()
           print(data2)
    elif choice==3:
            bookHolderName=input("enter the bookholdername:")
            mycursor.execute("select * from booklist where bookholdername=bookHolderName")
            data3=mycursor.fetchone()
            print(data3)   
    elif choice==4:
            library=input("enter the library id:")
            mycursor.execute("select * from booklist where LibraryID=libraryid")
            data4=mycursor.fetchone()
            print(data4)
    elif choice==5:
            break
    else:
            print("invalid choice")
```

else:
print("no record displayed")

> #**OUTPUT**
> Do you want to display any record??(y/n):y

Do you have information about the record??

1-bookid

2-bookname

3-bookholdername

4-library id

5-Exit

enter your choice:1

[]

enter the bookid:**2**

(**1**, ' Rd sharma', datetime.date(2022, 3, 18), datetime.date(2022, 4, 1), 'Ramesh', '**xuv1**')

Do you have information about the record??

1-bookid

2-bookname

3-bookholdername

4-library id

5-Exit

enter your choice:1

> [(2, 'Sumita arrora', datetime.date(2022, 4, 20), datetime.date(2022, 5, 4), 'suresh', 'xuv2'), (3, 'sadf', datetime.date(2022, 4, 1), datetime.date(2022, 4, 3), 'nasd', 'ads1'), (4, 'safw', datetime.date(2022, 4, 4), datetime.date(2022, 4, 7), 'afse', 'scw1'), (5, 'saf', datetime.date(2022, 4, 1), datetime.date(2022, 4, 11), 'dhd', 'wer3'), (6, 'asfasf', datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), datetime.date(2020, 1, 14), 'asfq', 'xvr3'), (7, 'aasd', datetime.date(2020, 4, 4), datetime.date(2020, 4, 7), 'asdqr', 'fddx1'), (8, 'asfa', datetime.date(2022, 7, 10), datetime.date(2022, 7, 15), 'asdsax', 'za1w'), (9, 'agd', datetime.date(2022, 7, 11), datetime.date(2022, 7, 15), 'asfxvs', 'asd2')]

Comment: WHERE bookid=bookID (FOR EXAMPLE) is testing bookid to itself try changing one of these bookids to be the bookid input ,whose name I would change,, (test by hardcoding then parameterise)

Comment: @P.Salmon can you pls explain in simple terms as i am new in this and don't know much about this

Comment: Remove print(mycursor.fetchall()) there is nothing to fetch and will throw an error. Amend first select to SELECT * FROM booklist WHERE bookid=2 run your script with choice == 1 and you should get a some returned values. I haven't used python in a while but I seem to recall you can build a variable which holds the sql script for execution.